# Why can the Android Launcher Shortcuts code be compiled when minSdkVersion is 21?

Tags: android

I'm learning the Android Launcher Shortcuts.

The code A is from the office sample [project](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/AppShortcuts).

I know that the Launcher Shortcuts API requires Android 7.1 (API 25) or higher.

The Code A can be compiled and run after I replace `minSdkVersion 25` with `minSdkVersion 21`, why?

**Code A**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.shortcutsample"
        minSdkVersion 25  //The app can be compiled if I replace it with minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this feature will be available only on API25+ devices, still you can develop such app also for older devices (assuming there will be more features than shortcuts, then it makes sense :) )

some new features may need some class/method call (like [ShortcutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager)), which isn't available on older APIs supported by app. then you have to use some `if` statement, like:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // or just >= 21
    // feature/method available on 5.0+
}
```

otherwise you will get e.g. `NoSuchMethodException` thrown

Comment: basically, compilation completes regardless of the api features you use, but you'll get runtime exceptions